# Maven project configuration for java tomcat application

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I'm having trouble setting up my project with maven. I always get that project must be pom or that it is missing a jar package. So here is what I want to do:

1. I have a main project that has web-inf folder for web, and can be run on tomcat if i export it as war:

   ```
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>main</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   ```
2. I have a module project that has main dependency so I can use all libraries from main project, but will be used as an extension to main project. I plan to have multiple modules like this:

   ```
   <groupId>com.example.modules</groupId>
   <artifactId>module-blogging</artifactId>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>module-blogging</name>

   <parent>
       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>main</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   ```
3. The third project I plan to have a deployable project that will only have main project and only modules I want to deploy in a war file.

   ```
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   ```

Is this thing even possible with maven? Because I always get that my project is missing some jar dependencies, or that the aggregation project cannot have war packaging.

Answer (score 1):

i have roughly the same scenario `3 modules` one of them is `deploy-able`
and all 3 modules included int one project

so i configured it by 4 `.pom` files as follows

### main-project.pom

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.#####</groupId>
    <artifactId>#########</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>########</name>



<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>         
        <###########.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</##########.version>
    </properties>



<modules>
        <module>#########-web</module>
        <module>#########-commons</module>
        <module>#########-services</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

### commons-module.pom

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>############</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.#####</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>###########-commons</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <dependencies>

ur own depends

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### services-module.pom

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>#######</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.########</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
ur depends
    </dependencies>

    <artifactId>########-services</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

### web-module.pom

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.#########</groupId>
        <artifactId>##########</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>#########-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>############</name>
    <url>http://##########.com</url>

    <dependencies>
UR DEPENDS
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>##############</finalName>
        <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>5</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <unpackTypes>war</unpackTypes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- configure war plugin to skip webxml -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- jetty plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.15.v20140411</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

### UPDATE

your project structure will be something like that:

```
main-project
    |
    ----commons-module
    |
    ----services-module
    | 
    ----web-module
```

to build and deploy the project

i'm using jetty for deployment

you can see its plugin in web-module pom

at your project root run that command to build the project and generate the war file `mvn clean install`

then change directory to be on the web-module and run the following command to deploy the war file `mvn jetty:run`

I hope it's helpful;

Comment: But this only creates a pom file for the main-project, not the war file I can deploy to tomcat.

Comment: build the main project and deploy the web module

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind.
My module blogging depends on main project which is war, and therefore when I try to build it through maven it says it cannot find artifact with jar.
The other thing is that I would like to have multiple project builds, the kind where i will have demo1, and demo2 building with different modules. And if I have to make shown folder structure, then I cannot implement it as I thought.